# Resource router hijacking all template groups

Tags: url, routing, template-routes, resource-router

I could swear this was working last week.

I've got Resource Router set up like so:

```
':url_title' => function($router) {
$router->setTemplate('addon/index');
$router->setGlobal('template', 'addon');
},
':url_title/faqs' => function($router) {
    $router->setTemplate('addon/faqs');
$router->setGlobal('template', 'addon');
},
':url_title/changelog' => function($router) {
    $router->setTemplate('addon/changelog');
$router->setGlobal('template', 'addon');
},
':url_title/documentation' => function($router) {
    $router->setTemplate('addon/documentation');
$router->setGlobal('template', 'addon');
}
```

and it works.

However, I've just started to notice that if I try /blog the template that gets served is addon/index.

'blog' is not a URL title that exists in the database and this is happening for other template groups as well.

Like I say, this has been working and only just seeing it has stopped coming back to the project this morning.

If I were to alter my routes like:

```
'blog' => 'blog',
'blog/:url_title' => 'blog/post',
'voucher' => 'voucher',
'members' => 'member',
':url_title' => function($router) {
$router->setTemplate('addon/index');
$router->setGlobal('template', 'addon');
},
```

it works, but I'd rather rely on native EE routing for these template groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:url_title` will match any string that *could* be a url title as it is converted to `([^/]+)` [1]

To stop this rule matching template groups, you can check that the match is for a real entry in the expected channel like this:

```
':url_title' => function($router, $wildcard) {
    // valid entry in the 'home' channel (id=3)?
    if ($wildcard->isValidUrlTitle(array('channel_id' => 3))) {
        $router->setTemplate('addon');
        $router->setGlobal('template', 'addon');
    }
},
```

[1] Note: `^` is added to the start and `$` to the end of the rule automatically by Resource Router, so the actual url pattern matched is `^([^/]+)$`